# reorder stacked bar chart with two levels ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this data:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  question category percent
  <chr>    <chr>      <dbl>
1 No       A           0.82
2 No       C           0.8 
3 No       B           0.77
4 Yes      B           0.23
5 Yes      C           0.2 
6 Yes      A           0.18
```

and I make a stacked bar chart:

```
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = category, y = percent, fill = question)) + 
  geom_col(position = "fill") + 
  coord_flip()
```

but what I really want is to arrange the bars descending in "Yes". That means Category "B" should be top, "C" in the middle", and "A" at the bottom.

If I didn't have a stacked chart I could do this with `reorder()`. But how can I do this with a stacked chart?

The data:

```
structure(list(question = c("No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"
), category = c("A", "C", "B", "B", "C", "A"), percent = c(0.82, 
0.8, 0.77, 0.23, 0.2, 0.18)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arrange` the data, set the factors and plot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data %>% 
  arrange(desc(question), percent) %>%
  mutate(category = factor(category, unique(category))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = category, y = percent, fill = question)) + 
  geom_col(position = "fill") + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: this works on the dummy data, but it doesn't work on my real data (which is the same as the dummy data, just with different names). why might this be the case?

Comment: Do you have `'Yes'`/`'No'` value in real data as well? Try changing the `arrange` line to `arrange(question != 'Yes', percent) %>%`

Comment: ah it was because the data were grouped. doing `ungroup()` before your stuff worked. why would grouping mess it up?

Comment: If your data is grouped then `mutate(category = factor(category, unique(category)))` will be done within each group and not for the entire dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually reorder the category variable by making in an ordered factor.

`dat$category <- factor(dat$category, levels = c('B', 'C', 'A'), ordered = T)`

Comment: Why hardcoding the `ordered = T` while converting category as factor?