# ordered bar chart with multiple groupings in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this ungrouped data (`dput()`'ed below):

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   category1 category2 value
   <chr>     <chr>     <dbl>
 1 A         x         0.200
 2 A         y         0.32 
 3 A         z         0.46 
 4 B         x         0.52 
 5 B         y         0.420
 6 B         z         0.28 
 7 C         x         0.3  
 8 C         y         0.26 
 9 C         z         0.440
10 D         x         0.34 
11 D         y         0.440
12 D         z         0.58
```

and I plot it:

```
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = category2, y = value, fill = as.factor(category1))) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

and now I want to order the bars within category2, descending in category1.

From this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66218647/reorder-stacked-bar-chart-with-two-levels-ggplot2/66218676?noredirect=1#comment117072439_66218676) I understand you have to arrange the data and create/order the factor. But it does not change anything, and I can't figure out why:

```
data %>% 
  arrange(desc(category1), value) %>%
  mutate(category2 = factor(category2, levels = unique(category2), ordered = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = category2, y = value, fill = as.factor(category1))) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
  coord_flip()
```

I also tried re-ordering the factor [per this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051040/ggplot2-how-to-sort-the-categories-in-horizontal-bar-charts), but it didn't do anything:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(category2 = factor(category2)) %>% 
  mutate(category2 = category2 %>% forcats::fct_reorder(value, sum)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = category2, y = value, fill = as.factor(category1))) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

edit: forgot to the add the data:

```
structure(list(category1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
"C", "C", "D", "D", "D"), category2 = c("x", "y", "z", "x", "y", 
"z", "x", "y", "z", "x", "y", "z"), value = c(0.2, 0.32, 0.46, 
0.52, 0.42, 0.28, 0.3, 0.26, 0.44, 0.34, 0.44, 0.58)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2):

If I got you right you could achieve your desired result by making use of an interaction variable and the `group` aesthetic like so:

1. Arrange your data by `category2` and `value`
2. Add a new category variable as the interaction of `category2` and `category1`
3. Set the order of the new category variable via `forecast::fct_inorder`
4. Map the the new category variable on the `group` aesthetic

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  arrange(category2, value) %>%
  mutate(
    category3 = interaction(category2, category1),
    category3 = forcats::fct_inorder(category3)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = category2, y = value, fill = category1, group = category3)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
data <- structure(list(category1 = c(
  "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C",
  "C", "C", "D", "D", "D"
), category2 = c(
  "x", "y", "z", "x", "y",
  "z", "x", "y", "z", "x", "y", "z"
), value = c(
  0.2, 0.32, 0.46,
  0.52, 0.42, 0.28, 0.3, 0.26, 0.44, 0.34, 0.44, 0.58
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  "1",
  "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"
))
```

Comment: wow, never knew about `interact()`. so is this the **only** way to do this? I get so confused by all these posts about ordering bars that say you have to order the factor

Comment: The issue is that you only reordered `category2`. However even reordering `category1` will not work as you can only have one order. That's why we need `category3` which allows to order `category1` by `value` for each level of `category2` independently. To the best of my knowledge this is the "simplest" approach to achieve this result.

Answer (score 1):

`tidytext::reorder_within` is built for this use case.

```
library(tidytext)
data %>% 
  mutate(category1b = reorder_within(category1, value, within = category2)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = category2, group = category1b, fill = as.factor(category1))) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]